# How to create XML endpoint in Flask?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, flask

I have the following property in SQLAlchemy:

```
@property
def serialize(self):
    return {
        'name' : self.name,
        'description' : self.description,
        'id' : self.id,
        'price' : self.price,
        'course' : self.course,
    }
```

For JSON, I just used `jsonify()`, how can I do it for XML?

Answer (score 7):

All `jsonify` is [doing](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/ec5811d0a15dc5ca2c5f231ac6aa79f9a107776e/flask/json.py#L247-L251) is dumping the arguments passed to it with `json` and setting the content-type of the response to `application/json`.  You would do the exact same thing for XML: dump the data (Python has the built-in [etree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#module-xml.etree.ElementTree) library or there's the more powerful [lxml](http://lxml.de/)) and set the content-type to `application/xml`.

There are many ways you could represent data using XML, so that's up to you, but the basic outline is:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.Element('root')  # name the root whatever you want
# add your data to the root node in the format you want
return app.response_class(ET.tostring(root), mimetype='application/xml')
```